# Using inversifyjs to inject container bindings to an instance of an existing object

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

Basically I would like to be responsible for the construction of the object, then use inversify to bind properties that are decorated to `@inject`.

I thought I could use `createChild` to bind the type to a value using `toConstantValue` or even `toDynamicValue`; however, it doesn't appear that either of these methods do any property binding.

*Example*

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container, inject, injectable } from "inversify";

const container = new Container();
container.bind(Container).toConstantValue(container);

@injectable()
class Foo {
  @inject(Container)
  public container: Container;
}

describe("inversify", () => {
  it("should inject for ctor", () => { //                    PASS
    const c = container.createChild();
    c.bind(Foo).toSelf();
    const result = c.get(Foo);
    expect(result.container).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("should inject for dynamic value", () => { //           FAIL
    const c = container.createChild();
    c.bind(Foo).toDynamicValue(() => new Foo());
    const result = c.get(Foo);
    expect(result.container).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("should inject for const value", () => { //             FAIL
    const c = container.createChild();
    c.bind(Foo).toConstantValue(new Foo());
    const result = c.get(Foo);
    expect(result.container).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

It seems like there should be an easy way to bind properties without deferring the construction of the object into the `Container`?